# Consider an ordinal variable as continuos for correlation with a continous variable

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data, continuous-data, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I need to analyse the results of a survey. Among the different questions I have: *"How happy did you feel last month"*?. There are 5 possible answers:

1. Not at all
2. Not very
3. Somewhat
4. Very
5. Completely

Now, I would like to measure if there is a correlation between `age` and `happiness`. One option is to simply plot the `age` on the x-axis (from 18 to 99), the `happiness` values (from 1 to 5) on the y-axis and then check for a possible trend. However, I'd like to have a more rigorous statistical test. Given that `happiness` is an ordinal variable, would it be wrong to treat it as a `continuous` variable and calculate either `Pearson` or `Spearman` correlation coefficient? If this approach is correct, can it be done for binary variable as well? E.g `gender`: `Male` or `Female`?

Comment: A standard scatter plot won't help much unless you arrange (e.g. by jittering) to get a visual impression of how many people plot at each happiness point. (Ties on age could be a problem too.) There's  a deeper question, which is why you expect a linear or monotonic relationship at all.  Making dubious (or unfounded) assumptions about your data can't count as "rigorous". It might count as a pragmatic decision to use a correlation method if that matches patterns on a plot.

Comment: I have no a-priori knowledge, hence I have no expectation on seeing a linear relationship. That's why I need to test if a relationship exist.

Comment: But "a relationship" could mean many things, not just a linear relationship. Correlation won't help much there.